# Django can't find static file for admin

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Hello and thank you in advance.

I have django installed on Bluehost.  Everything seems to be working, but the admin module isn't seeing the static files so the admin pages are not formatted.

I am a noob and I am not sure where to start troubleshooting, any help is appreciated.  Please let e know what information would be helpful to supply.

```
    <pre>
        # Django settings for acme project.

    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG



= DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'XXXXXXX',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'XXXXXXXX',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXX',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                 # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'home/public_html/chicken/static'
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '#rrbgcl4dl5sr$7)5pb5)b+4tt$9glpj)zs0+--edu!id9&amp;vpt'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'acme.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'acme.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
</pre>

django.fcgi (in a sub directory under public_html)

<pre>
#!/home/acmefant/bin/python
import sys, os 
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/acmefant/django_src") 
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/acmefant/django_projects/acme") 
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer 
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'acme.settings' 
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler 
WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
</pre>
```

.htaccess (in the same sub directory)

```
<pre>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi 
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(django\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /chicken/django.fcgi/$1 [L]

</pre>
```

I have been troubleshooting this for a few days and I am at the end of my rope..

Thank you,

dp

Comment: If you haven't already, peruse this post (I've used it myself): http://blog.ruedaminute.com/2011/01/2011-installation-instructions-for-django-on-bluehost/

Comment: I have studied that, and tried the suggestions as well as http://alextreppass.co.uk/getting-django-working-on-bluehost

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I moved the site to WebFaction and it works.

Comment: This doesn't really help anyone who has the same problem. Do you know why it works on your new host when it didn't work on the old one?

Comment: That isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following is included in your settings.py

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Comment: Tried this as well.  no luck here...  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to set `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to a fully qualified url. 
Like

`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://yourdoman.com/static/admin/'`

and make sure your server is serving the static files.

Comment: I have the static files in a directory much like the one above.  I created the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX key in my setting.py files and pointed it to the directory and still no-joy.  I was SO HOPEFUL...Thank you.  COuld this have to do with my .htaccess file?  the line: RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]   ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs across this, bluehost does not allow the normal methods that you would use to direct requests for static resources on the admin page via mod_rewrite (detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files)). Specifically, `Alias` and `Options +FollowSymLinks` are disallowed.

The way we got this working was creating a `static/` dir under `public_html`. We then copied all of the relevant Django `css/img/js` folder structures into that static folder, and used a simpler `.htaccess` file:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(mysite.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was create a directory called static and copy over python/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/* to there. Done.